# Using "unsigned short" data type breaks loops

Tags: c++

I was making a simple C++ code that takes multiple lines of input, the first line defines how many numbers the user will enter, then he enters them all, the code will reverse every number of them and print the reversed version of every number space-separated, the surprise I faced is that, for some reason, using `unsigned short` data type causes a weird break in the big loop after the first iteration, but with `long long` data type it works well, I was curious why this happens? although I was using numbers way smaller than 10^4.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned short x;
    unsigned short num;

    cin >> x;

    string a[x];

    for (long long i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        a[i] = to_string(num);
    }

    for (long long i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (long long j = a[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your input and output, and also the expected output

Comment: I would dearly love to find whatever source new students learning C++ keep cookie-cutting VLAs (variable length arrays) from and have it scorched from the earth forever. `string a[x];` is *not* standard C++ compliant, and I curse the day *some* compiler vendors ever considered it "helpful" to add as an extension. Anyway, regarding your problem, `j >= 0;` is always true when `j` is an unsigned type.

Comment: `j >= 0` is never true if `j` is `unsigned short`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Um.. it's always true; not never true.

Comment: @WhozCraig are u suggesting to use vectors for declaring VLAs? what's the standard way?

Comment: @y_159 *yes*. that is exactly what should be used in this scenario.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oops, yeah.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh right!, it will never go below 0 forever for any unsinged datatypes, the outer loop was not broken, the inner loop just have gone infinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unsigned type can *never* be less than zero. The language standard supports underflow/overflow to wrap to the opposite end of the domain in both scenarios. Eg:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned short i = 0;
    --i;
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
65535
```

Therefore, you can put any legal value you want in `i` in the above code, and decrement it to the end of the time  for this universe and the next; the expression `i>=0` will *always* be true.

In short, the signed-ness, not the width, (long vs short) is the issue you're experiencing. Therefore, your inner-loop is infinite if `j` is ever an unsigned type (short or otherwise; makes no difference). If you're headstrong on using that construct anyway, you can do it as follows:

```
for (long long i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for (auto j = a[i].length(); j-- > 0;)
        cout << a[i][j] << " ";

    cout << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, since this loop is just printing string characters separated by whitespace in reverse order, you can use the reverse iterator members that `std::string` provides:

```
for (long long i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for (auto it = a[i].rbegin(); it != a[i].rend(); ++it)
        cout << *it << ' ';

    cout << endl;
}
```